# How to install Perrix gaming mouse on Ubuntu?

Tags: drivers, mouse, hardware

When I put my gaming mouse into the USB slot the light comes on but my cursor won't move and the buttons won't work. I stupidly threw away the CD that came with the mouse but they have the program  available on the website and so I downloaded it and when I click on it, it just open as a file and not a executable program. What can i do?

Comment: Do you have a link to the site? That might help.

Comment: This is the site. http://www.perixx.com/en/service/download.htm

Comment: Yep. That's only a Windows driver.

Comment: I see. Thank you. Is there anymouse you could reccommend that is has multibuttons and would work on ubuntu? Thank you once again.

Comment: Its a bit tricky, involving needing to compile a kernel module, but roccat has an open source mouse driver for many of its mice - I haven't gotten around to getting mine working yet, but the roccat xtd I own is *awesome*. Quite a few of razer's mice are supported under linux as well with razercfg, which is a usermode program.

Comment: Some mice would also let you configure them in windows , and run those macros in linux - my logitech G300 does that

Comment: @GregoryHouse Are you able to use the Perixx mouse? I have the same problem with model Perimice-718. I couldn't find a driver nor `cat /dev/input/<device>` doesn't print out data stream. Although the mouse looks like make two files at `/dev/input/by-path` (ref: https://thehackerdiary.wordpress.com/2017/04/21/exploring-devinput-1/).

Comment: @GregoryHouse I solved my trouble by replacing with the good battery on my wireless mouse ;).

Answer (score 2):

There's no reason a mouse shouldn't work at all without drivers - the drivers are primarily to enable extra keys, or to send commands *to* the mouse. While I'd test this on a windows system to be sure (and to rule out the possibility that it simply dosen't work in windows), chances are the *mouse* is faulty (and i've had faulty mice work perfectly as a mouse, I just had problems changing settings on it) and that you ought to get it replaced.

There's a few things I'd check in troubleshooting the mouse in question in *ubuntu*

1. check if the mouse is even detected with `sudo lsusb`
2. /dev/input/by-path has a series of files referring to input devices. using cat on one of those files will result in a series of ... odd looking characters when you use the device. `xev' is a x specific command that does similarly, but with more specific detail.

If your device is *not* in /dev/input/by-path , or lsusb, something is off. I'd borrow a windows box (as I suggested earlier), plug it in, and see if it works there (and if it does, I'd be baffled) and if it still dosen't, RMA that darned thing cause its broken.

Comment: Actually the mouse works perfectly on my windows everything works. It just doesn't work on a linux operating system.

Comment: ok, that rules out the mouse itself being faulty, curious.